# What kind of upgrades to a BMC AC02 hybrid?

Tags: hybrid-bike

I bought a hybrid bike about one month ago. It's a BMC Alpenchallenge AC02 Tiagra. Have been having a blast on it to the point of considering to eventually get into road bikes

Full Specs can be seen here:
http://www.bmc-switzerland.com/int-en/bikes/lifestyle/mountainroad-alpenchallenge-ac02-tiagra/

**Chainwheel:**
Shimano Tiagra, 50-39-30T

**Cassette:**
Shimano Tiagra, 11-34

**Tyres:**
Continental Sport Contact II, 35mm

**Rims:**
DT SWISS R522D

So the question is, if you were to do some upgrades what would you get?

I plan to get a road bike in **1.5-2 year**s time. In the mean time I'd like to use this one to train (likely uphilly stuff like http://www.cycling-challenge.com/col-de-la-faucille - over 1000m altitude). In terms of improving performance/handling/speed what kind of sensible upgrades can be done for a budgeted **$500 tops**?

Thanks in advance, would much appreciate your inputs!

Comment: Any money spent replacing still functioning parts will likely be wasted. you likely won't see or feel the improvements. Your efforts would be best spent riding and training to increase speed and endurance. If something wears out or breaks replace it possibly with an upgrade.

Comment: I would put the $500 in the bank and use to either upgrade sooner, or upgrade to a better bike. Putting it into you current bike will not significantly add to the bikes resale value.

Comment: I would spend some of it on quality front and rear lights, a helmet, and padded cycling pants/gloves.  Possibly a bright riding shirt too. There is no part of the bike that will be worn enough to need replacement.

Comment: Certainly not after a month. If it's so new, one might ask why the OP doesn't simply return it and buy a nicer bike with the n+500 dollars he has.

Comment: To reinforce other comments from a different perspective: That's already pretty fast and well-specced for a hybrid.  You can't really improve on the gearing or the tyres and you're already planning to upgrade the frame when you're ready.  Personally I'd regard the ability to carry some luggage as an upgrade, but that's a matter for you to choose based on your use.

Comment: Thanks all for the comments, some very good ones and surely makes a lot of sense. I was going to return or sell the bike and add the extra dollars for a more proper road bike... but I figured I will keep this bike for daily commute or if ever I need to put baby seat :-) 

I know that there's very little difference between tiagra and 105... I was just thinking of turning the bike into 105 eventually and have 50-34/11-32 and 105 shifters (?)... not sure which other parts must be changed/kept

but like others have mentioned very little one can improve on the gearing side

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best upgrades would be a set of clipless pedals, compatible shoes, and some nice cycling clothes and helmet. And maybe a good set of lights. You can carry all these over to your next bike.

Another nice upgrade is a bike repair stand and a basic bike repair toolkit.

Finally, a good GPS bike computer or GPS watch will set you back a few hundred dollars.

I think you get the idea. There are no "upgrades" to an essentially new bike itself that need to be made. Only buy things that will encourage you to cycle more (Strava premium membership!) or that you can take with you to the next bike.

Comment: Strava on a smartphone works well enough for me, no need for a poncy garmin.

Comment: True. So spend the money on a nice smartphone mount for your bike. :)